# How to reduce DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

As you can see from the code below, we are using innerHTML to insert html to the page. With every innerHTML, the browser will reflow and repaint which causes slowness if the we have a lot innerHTML or complex DOM. Is there a way to change the content by using only one innerHTML request? How we can increase the performance here?

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>test </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1"> I'm div 1</div>
<div id="2"> I'm div 2</div>
<div id="3"> I'm div 3</div>
<div id="4"> I'm div 4</div>
<div id="5"> I'm div 5</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML='<b>Im New value 1 </b>';
document.getElementById("3").innerHTML='<b>Im New value 3  </b>';
document.getElementById("4").innerHTML='<b>Im New value 4  </b>';
document.getElementById("5").innerHTML='<b>Im New value 5  </b>';
</script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Make a container, create your entire HTML string - append it all at once.

Comment: Could you explain more? Please notice the modified div elements are not in order.

Comment: What is the use case regarding your code? If you do this on page load, then it should be handled server side

Comment: @tymeJV I heard regarding performance, better is to use [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) instead of any string manipulation

Comment: @A.Wolff -- I'll have to check that out - thanks

Comment: @A. Wolff I'm not using it during load page, my code is just simple example. In my case I want to show extra details on the page when event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend from where the slowness is affecting your site, at least modifying dom in one call can generate leaner css transitions, the best performance over the DOM is to have porn JavaScript with documentFragmanent as [@A.Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) said.

Maybe an option is to reload sections of html as in my example, reloading/overwriting larger portions of dom you can increase the performance. If each dom childs  are updated individual by events than you have a messy website, rethink your page group elements in modules (as in section of page), apply priority rules over events. 
Try as much as possible to update large chunks of dom with one call.

```js
var containerString = $("#wrapper").clone();

$(containerString).find('#1').html('<b>Im New value 1 </b>');
$(containerString).find('#3').html('<b>Im New value 3 </b>');
$(containerString).find('#4').html('<b>Im New value 4 </b>');
$(containerString).find('#5').html('<b>Im New value 5 </b>');

$("#wrapper").html("").append(containerString)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 <title>test </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="1"> I'm div 1</div>
    <div id="2"> I'm div 2</div>
    <div id="3"> I'm div 3</div>
    <div id="4"> I'm div 4</div>
    <div id="5"> I'm div 5</div>
  </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```